# Как сделать автотабуляцию?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 4 разных инпута, в которые вводится по 1 символу. Возник вопрос, как реализовать следующее:

1) Плавный перенос фокуса на следующий инпут при заполнении текущего?

2) Плавный перенос фокуса на предыдущий инпут при удалении символа в текущем(при нажатии Backspace)?

Вот заготовка: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ANTON_ZIN_/pen/mNxQKQ)

```js
var numField = document.getElementsByClassName("numField");
    for(var i = 0; i < numField.length; i++) {
        numField[i].onkeydown = function(e){    
            if((e.which >=48 && e.which <=57) || (e.which>=96 && e.which <=105) || e.which==8 || (e.which>=37 && e.which<=40) || e.which==46) { 
                return true;
            } else { 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}

body {
    background: #333;  
}

form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.field {
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: #222;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
}

.field:focus {
    background: #111;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="text" class="field numField" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" class="field numField" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" class="field numField" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" class="field numField" maxlength="1">
</form>
```

Буду благодарен за предоставленные идеи и возможные решения!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не трогал твой html и css, а просто добавил библиоткеку jquery и вот такой код

```
$('.field').on("input", function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next().focus();
  }
});

$('.field').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 8)
    $(this).prev().focus();
});
```

Вводишь символ, и тебя перебрасывает на другой инпут. При backspace - стирает, и становится активным предыдущий инпут

Answer (score 0):

тоже самое без использования jquery

```
//выделение первого input
document.getElementsByClassName("numField")[0].focus();
//перебор
document.querySelectorAll(".numField").forEach((num)=>{
  num.onkeyup=function(e){
    //тут та-же логика что и у Daniel
    //только добавил проверку на нажатие Tab и следующего элемента
    if((this.value.length>0)&&(e.key!=='Tab')&&(this.nextElementSibling)){
      this.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
    if((e.keyCode == 8)&&(this.previousElementSibling)){
      this.previousElementSibling.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Сплошная каша: `getElementsByClassName("numField")[0].focus()` а ниже `querySelectorAll`; стрелки тут для чего.